# How do I remove the virtual disk (iso file) from the computer completely

Tags: iso, delete

So i was downloading a game via an ISO file and now i have a virtual disk for like forever.
It was mounted like a disk and when i deleted the iso file it just was standing there menacingly. Is it possible to remove these with terminal?

Comment: Can you right click on the virtual disk and select "unmount"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the cli/terminal if you do 'df -h', it will show you the path of every mounted device.  Normally iso's are mounted as 'loop' devices and are 100% used (/dev/loop41p1 in my example below).

```
Filesystem              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/loop41p1           4.8G  4.8G     0 100% /media/youruser/mounted_media_folder
```

Usually, this works to umount the folder.

```
$ umount /media/youruser/mounted_media_folder
```